# что делать если пишешь в паскале программу: Встречено 'end', а ожидался оператор

Tags: pascal

```
Program myFirstProgram;

begin
  writeln ('привет !');
and.
```

Comment: Наверное, надо разобраться с синтаксисом языка...

Comment: вместо and напишите end

Comment: поиск программ - это что?

Answer (score 4):

Добрый день, Иван. В `Pascal` конструкция `begin/end` является составным оператором. Также `begin` и `end` являются операторными скобками, то есть операторы внутри этой конструкции рассматриваются как единый оператор.

Подробнее можно ознакомиться здесь [Начальные сведения о программах на языке Pascal](http://pascal.net.ru/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5+Pascal+(3)) и здесь [Конструкция begin...end](http://pascal.net.ru/begin). Компилятор ожидает end после begin, однако не нашёл его.